# Java Android WebView Displaying a string

Tags: java, android, string, webview, rendering

i have an application that fetch html from a websites, exactly in a webpage permitted only tu logged in user, so i have setted the login cookie and i get back the html webpage to a string, i tryied to easily take this string off from emulator, but i can't do copy-paste trought emulator-pc, does someone know how can i load a webview to reder my string and make me seeing if i am logged in and all work or not?
If it's possible i'd like to directly render the string, without saving it to an html file and opening it... is this possible?
Thanks, matteo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting webview content form String:

```
public static void loadHtmlToWebView(WebView view, String html) { 
    view.loadData(Base64.encodeToString(html.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT) , "text/html", "base64");
}
```